# How to decode or encode data sent through HC-05 with arduino uno?

Tags: python, bluetooth, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm trying to send data with the HC-05 bluetooth module with an arduino uno. I am successful in both sending and receiving data. However the data being received is not human readable. I am using pybluez to connect to the module. below is the data received:

```
received: ÿ
received: °■
received: ÿ
received: °
received: ÿ°
received: ÿ°
received: ÿ°
received: ÿ°
received: ÿ°
received: ÿ°
```

here is my .ino

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(2,3);
void setup(){
    mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
   if(mySerial.available())
       mySerial.write(mySerial.read());
}
```

here is my .py

```
# simple inquiry example
import bluetooth
import sys

addr = "20:16:12:05:69:99"
port  = 1

sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
sock.connect((addr,port))
print 'connected'
sock.settimeout(15.0)
sock.send('10\r\n')
count = 0
while (count<10):
    data = sock.recv(12)
    print 'received: %s'%data
    sock.send(data)
    count += 1
sock.close()
```

Comment: What sort of data are you expecting to receive?

Comment: Print the data in *hexadecimal* format within your *python* script, it's better.

Comment: @IntrepidBrit right now, i'm just trying to send/receive anything so i can get it to work. But the long term goal is send data collected from sensors hooked up to the arduino. So to answer directly i intend on sending floats and doubles

Comment: Why do you have TX and RX on the same pin?

Comment: @gre_gor that was a mistype when typing the question, the pins are 2,3 respectively